# gem cocoonを使った多対多のパラメータ送信ができない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

現在、gemのcocoonを使って、動的にフォームを追加し、保存するようにしたいと考えています。
しかし、viewでは、フォームを追加したり削除したりなど、うまく動かすことができるのですが、送信してもうまくパラメーターが渡せていない状態となっています。
どのようにしたら、うまくパラメータを渡すことができ、登録できるのでしょうか？
テーブルは、多対多になっており、中間テーブルを置いています。
下記に現在のコードを記します。よろしくお願い致します。

controller

```
  def new
    @newarea = Area.new
    @newarea.area_cities.build
  end

  def create
    @newarea = Area.new(areacity_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @newarea.save
        format.html { redirect_to [:admin, @newarea]
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: [:admin, @newarea] }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @newarea.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
  def areacity_params
    params.require(:area).permit(:code, :prefecture_id, area_cities_attributes: [:id, :city_id, :area_id, :_destroy])
  end
```

view

```
 = form_for @newarea, :url => {:action => 'create'} do |f|
      = f.hidden_field :prefecture_id, :value => @prefecture.id
      = f.hidden_field :code, :value => @area.code + 1
      = f.fields_for :area_cities do |builder|
        = render 'area_city_fields', f: builder
      = link_to_add_association "エリアを追加する", f, :area_cities
      %br
      = link_to "キャンセル", admin_locations_path, class: "btn btn-default"
      = f.submit "保存", class: "btn btn-primary"
```

model

city.rb

```
class City < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :prefecture
  has_many :requests  has_many :area_cities, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :cities, through: :area_cities
end
```

area.rb

```
class Area < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :prefecture
  has_many :area_cities, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :cities, through: :area_cities
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :area_cities, allow_destroy: true
end
```

area_city.rb

```
class AreaCity < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :area
  belongs_to :city

  validates :area_id, :city_id, :presence => true
end
```

Comment: 具体的にどのような期待していないパラメータが送信されてきているのか記載できますか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。パラメータは、 ' "area"=>{"prefecture_id"=>"44", "code"=>"3", "area_cities_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"city_id"=>"1813", "_destroy"=>"false"} 'となっており、cocoonで増やしたフォームのパラメータが持ってこれていない状態です。